# Upload pictures to my app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I´m designing a new app for an iPad. This app will work with a barcode scanner, and when it scans a code, it will show an image asociated.

I was thinking to build that asociating de barcode to an image name for example:
 - Barcode 09090909 will show 09090909.png picture
 - Barcode 19191919 will show 19191919.png picture
....

I think that there is no problem with that, but the problem comes when I need to add new barcode/pictures to the app. How can I send a new picture to my App? I see that when you develop on XCode and build you App, all the data goes into de App.

Any help or clue? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simple load them on the fly from your server, but then a network connection is required. To load them async from an server you can use this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t image_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.app.imageQueue", NULL);
dispatch_queue_t main_queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

dispatch_async(image_queue, ^{
  NSString *URLString = @"http://example.com/images/19191919.png";
  NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
  dispatch_async(main_queue, ^{
    [imageView setImage:image];
  });
});
```

If you want you can also save the image to the cache dir (using the document dir is not recommended because it will collide with [Apples iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/)) and check before downloading an image twice, then the code will look like this:

```
NSString *fileName = @"19191919.png";
NSString *URLBaseString = @"http://example.com/images/";
NSString *URLString = [URLBaseString stringByAppendingString:fileName];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachePath = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *dataPath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath] )
{
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
   [imageView setImage:image];
}
else
{
  dispatch_async(image_queue, ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
    dispatch_async(main_queue, ^{
      [imageView setImage:image];
    });
  });
}
```

**This code has not been tested, but should work. Note that I'm relying on ARC to manage memory.**

Comment: Thanks! But the iPad will be in a place where there is no conection. We are going to use an USB Barcode Scanner also because we need the app to be fast, so downloading pictures from a server is not an option for now.... thansk anyway ;)